# "less than" in ORACLE for two varchars?

Tags: sql, oracle

I had an assignment question:

```
Find the celebs that have been in relationship with the same celeb. 
The result should be (celeb1, celeb2, celeb3) triples, 
meaning that celeb1 and celeb2 have been in relationship with celeb3.
```

Now the table "Relationships" have celeb1 and celeb2 fields..where the value is a VARCHAR.

My solution to the problem was:

```
  CREATE VIEW Celeb1Rels AS
SELECT celeb1 AS c1, celeb2 AS c2 FROM relationships;

CREATE VIEW Celeb2Rels AS
SELECT celeb1 AS c2, celeb2 AS c3 FROM relationships;

SELECT * FROM Celeb1Rels NATURAL JOIN Celeb2Rels;
```

and it works fine. However the instructor posted his solution and he had:

```
SELECT X.celeb1, Y.celeb1, X.celeb2
FROM Relationships X, Relationships Y
WHERE X.celeb2=Y.celeb2 AND X.celeb1<Y.celeb1;
```

I don't understand why he is using X.celeb1 < Y.celeb1
It does work and give the right output, but I thought the "<" was used for comparing numbers?

Can anyone explain what the "<" is doing in this instance? and how it behaves when comparing VARCHARS?

Comment: *sigh*; is this the sort of thing teachers are stooping to to keep people interested nowadays? Why celebrities? Couldn't they have decided upon scientists or some other group of people who're useful... (this is in no way a comment on your question - just your teachers or more likely their bosses)

Comment: It was part of a larger database with Movies, albums, celeb relationships, celeb enemies and so on. I guess this was done so it would be easy to ask for queries like "The celebs who starred in a movie together but are considered enemies"

Comment: @Ben because scientists aren't as promiscuous as celebrities? :)

Comment: I hope you've also noticed the use of aliases - so that the same table is referenced multiple times in the same query, without having to introduce views.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is so that you don't get duplicate relationships, Take for instance 2 hypothetical relationships between celeb1 and celeb2, and celeb1 and celeb3, you want the result

```
celeb2, celeb3, celeb1
```

You need the second inequality operator to ensure that the table doesn't join on the same relationship (i.e. celeb1 & Celeb2 joining back to celeb1 & celeb2). If you were to use your instructors query and amend it so instead of `<` you were to use not equals `<>` though, you would get the result:

```
celeb2, celeb3, celeb1
celeb3, celeb2, celeb1
```

But these rows show the same thing but in a different order, the `>` inequality operator just ensures that the 2nd column is always a name alphabetically after the 1st column.

So to summarise the `>` operator when applied to varchars works alphabetically, so `'a' < 'b'`, `'abc' > 'aaa'` etc.

Comment: Do I need to worry about duplicates in my solutions? (using Natural join) I have ran both queries on the sample database provided and they both output the same results.

Comment: There are still good reasons to use the older joinging synatx, at least with Oracle.  ANSI 92 joins can lead to sub-optimal executions plans.  For example, http://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2012/07/16/ansi-outer-2/

Comment: I get different results when comparing the two queries you posted. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/56dc3/5), but for demonstration I have done one query using `<>` rather than `<`, to show the duplication.

Comment: @APC Interesting, I have removed there reference to ANSI 89 joins from my answer as it appears there is a compelling reason to use them.

Comment: It is a fair point. I generally prefer the ANSI syntax, particulary for outer joins, so it is particularly galling that those are the joins which appear to be most susceptible to performance bugs.

Answer (score 2):

I guess to exclude doubled records for example:

If `(A,B)` and `(B,C)` in this table then if query is without `AND X.celeb1<Y.celeb1` we get

`(A,B,C)` and `(B,C,A)`in the output. Adding this condition we output only one record `(A,B,C)` as soon as `A < C`.

Comment: please be more careful when reviewing tag wikis. You just approved two [wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits#suggested-edits/1513111?&_suid=1360763873890030766189238777785) [edits](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits#suggested-edits/1513009?&_suid=136076394562501405663346613258) in a row that clearly plagiarized text from Wikipedia without attributing the source. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The instructor's solution produces triples, where CELEB2 is in two relationships.  This part of the WHERE clause ...

```
X.celeb1<Y.celeb1
```

... ensures that you only get rows for three different celebrities (i.e. it avoids matching the same record against itself) and you only get one row for each threesome.

Less than works exactly as you think it would, it sorts alphabetically.  So `'ANDY GARCIA' < 'ANDY KAUFMAN'` is true.

Things to watch out for:

- it uses ASCII values and thus is case sensitive.   Which means `'andy garcia' < 'ANDY KAUFMAN'` is false.
- numbers get sorted alphabetically as well, so `'11' < '2'` is true.

---

> "I had no idea about this sorting issue"

It is possible to make Oracle sort case insenstively, by setting the NLS_SORT parameter.  However this won't change comparisons; for that we need to change the NLS_COMP parameter to `LINGUISTIC`.  These are not default behaviour simply because there's too much code out there which might rely on case-senstive sorting.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch5lingsort.htm#NLSPG290).

Comment: Not relevant to your question, but coming from a SQL-Server background I had no idea about this sorting issue. Interestingly (to me at least) of the 5 DBMS that are supported on SQL Fiddle, only Oracle and SQLite exhibit the behaviour described regarding Uppper/lower case comparisons. **Examples:** [Postgresql](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/766), [Oracle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/7270), [SQL-Server](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8782), [MySQL](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/7412), [SQLite](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/d41d8/377)

Comment: @GarethD The behaviour in Oracle is dependent upon the [`NLS_SORT`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams153.htm#REFRN10127) and [`NLS_COMP`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25513/initparams143.htm#REFRN10117) session parameters ([SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/7279))